# Running python after copying virtualenv dir onto Windows without python installed

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv directory created on a Windows machine, and which I'm copying into the same absolute path on a virgin windows machine that does not have python installed. On the first pass, python.exe failed on the virgin machine because it could not locate python27.dll. I then returned to the first machine and copied python27.dll from C:\Windows\System32 into the virtualenv \Scrips folder, and repeated the procedure. python.exe then failed on the virgin machine with the following error: ImportError: no module named functools.

This issue seems linked to the following fix to virtualenv: https://github.com/techtonik/virtualenv/commit/bd2fb414d016be7462d19bf9116117ac5aa9b019 . I was using virtualenv 1.7.1.2 and python 2.7. Any ideas?

Comment: Why copy a virtualenv at all? It can be really easily rebuild: `pip freeze --local > requirements.txt` and on the other machine `pip install -r requirements.txt` (in both cases the virtualenv should be active and have been created with `--distribute`)

Comment: My question is simply, can virtualenv work without an installed python? How can I get around this limitation? It's a response to http://bugs.python.org/msg136205 .

Comment: @TheifMaster The use case is that of modifying a virtual machine file structure such that python is executable from the moment the machine boots, i.e. before a pip command could be executed

Comment: If you want to run stuff your program without installing python, try py2exe, cx_freeze, pyInstaller, and similars

Answer (score 0):

A virtualenv is not a complete Python install.  It is just an environment that uses an existing Python install and provides an isolated environment to install packages into.  Do not expect a given virtualenv to work except exactly where it was created (where 'where' includes the computer it is on).

For deployment there's PEX and PyInstaller and various other options.

Answer (score -1):

From one of your comments:

> My question is simply, can virtualenv work without an installed python?

No, read the ['Making Environments Relocatable' in virtualenv documentation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv#making-environments-relocatable)

Quoting the most important:

> Note: this option is somewhat experimental, and there are probably caveats that have not yet been identified. Also this does not currently work on Windows.

Comment: Despite the documentation, you can relocate virtualenv from Windows Machine to Windows Machine as long as its relocated to the same absolute path. However, this has only worked empircally as long as the second Windows machine already had the same python distro installed

Comment: It may work, but is totally unsupported and may break at any moment. In my opinion you are trying to do it the wrong way, just make a batch to reconstruct the virtualenv if it is supposed to be used by developers, or make an executable with py2exe, cx_freeze, pyInstaller or anything similar for endusers.